# Disable mouse acceleration on Android

Tags: android-x86, mouse, prime-os

I am using PrimeOS on my laptop. I have noticed that when I move a mouse slowly for about an inch, consider it travels some distance on screen line about 2 inches. But when I move the mouse rapidly for 1 inch as before, the distance traveled by the cursor is much more like about 3.5 inches.

I want to disable this mouse acceleration to get the same displacement of the pointer at both slow and fast speeds.

Comment: There's [no API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170313462) for that unfortunately, except on some of the latest SHIELD products that check for a `com.nvidia.rawCursorInput` manifest property.

Answer (score 1):

Install [SetEdit](https://github.com/MuntashirAkon/SetEdit) app, then on the System Table, find: Pointer Speed, then change its value from 1 to 0.

Comment: At least on samsung phones it [seems](https://old.reddit.com/r/SamsungDex/comments/gsrspx/any_update_on_disabling_mouse_acceleration/hqeq2u6/) like [this](https://github.com/MuntashirAkon/SetEdit) might work.

Comment: The property in question accepts a wide range of values, at least [-5; 5], not just 0/1. Works exactly how you'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Open **Settings** > **General management** > **Mouse and trackpad**

Change **Enhance pointer precision** from the default value of **enabled** to **disabled**.

This will disable mouse acceleration in both Android and Samsung Dex.

Comment: The setting is in Android so plus oned it. But I  don't know if its in PrimeOs